# How to import the json package into a java file?

Tags: java, json, jar, terminal, sublimetext2

So I am new to using JSON and I am trying to make a JSONObject by importing org.json.JSONObject in my java file but when I try to compile this file I get the message " package org.json does not exist ".

I want to be able to use the JSON package and compile my java files. All the questions that ask about importing json that I have come across refer to a specific IDE but I am fairly new to cs and so I haven't gotten the hang of using an IDE and right now I am using sublime 2 and working off my terminal.

I have tried fixing this issue by downloading the json 1.1.1 jar file from this website

https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

and have put this jar file inside my project folder with my project.java file. I have been searching everywhere on how I can compile my java file and I know that I have to create a classpath for it but I am not 100% sure why. I have also been trying to make the classpath for hours now but haven't been able to do it correctly as my java file still won't compile.

I have tried to run these on my terminal but neither work

```
javac -classpath json-simple-1.1.1.jar Project.java

javac -classpath json.jar Project.java
```

Can anyone guide me on how to create a classpath to use the json package in my java file?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use IDE

but from command line you need to pass current directory and the jar in `classpath` so it would be like

```
javac -cp .:json-simple-1.1.1.jar Project.java
```

Comment: when I try this it still won't compile it errors saying that it cannot find symbol JSONObject what am I doing wrong?

Comment: does that jar have that class?

Comment: I think it only supports building a JSONObject with no parameters I am trying to make a JSONObject like this  JSONObject returnmssg = new JSONObject(in.readLine()); is there a json jar file that might be able to support this thanks.

Comment: right now I am using this jar file http://json-simple.googlecode.com/files/json-simple-1.1.1.jar from this website https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ this is the error that I am getting  --- Challenge.java:44: error: no suitable constructor found for JSONObject(String)
JSONObject retmssg = new JSONObject(in.readLine()); constructor JSONObject.JSONObject(Map) is not applicable
(actual argument String cannot be converted to Map by method invocation conversion)
constructor JSONObject.JSONObject() is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: I decompiled it it has no constructor that takes String

Comment: only     `public JSONObject() {}` and `public JSONObject(Map map) {super(map);}`

Comment: Is there any way that I could make a JSONObject that takes in a string?

Comment: You want [`new JSONParser().parse(jsonString);`](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)